# Rename the [masks] tag to [masks-a-new-generation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, rename-request

Since we can't make a system tag look different, when possible we should probably expand system tags so they don't look like common game terms.

*Masks: A New Generation* is the complete text used in the trade dress of all books I could find for the RPG called "Masks" for short in its own text. Renaming the tag from [masks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masks) to [masks-a-new-generation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masks-a-new-generation) will create a tag that more definitively looks like a book title without creating ambiguity about any existing products.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me. I'll happily action it in a day or two if there is no community disagreement.

Comment: I think it's worth noting explicitly that we've had at least one user get confused by this tag recently (on a question I asked where I relied on the tag to make the relevant system clear) - the problem's come up, and there's a clear benefit to the change.

Comment: ^Specifically [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170134/what-happens-when-a-character-fails-to-reject-influence-that-would-put-a-label-a#comment455126_170134)

Comment: @linksassin Has it been long enough?

Comment: @Pureferret: Seems so :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The change has been made

I left this for a few days to see if there were any arguments against it. There haven't been any, reasonable or otherwise so I didn't see the point in waiting any longer. I have now updated the tag. You can find the 11 effected questions under the new tag [masks-a-new-generation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masks-a-new-generation).